How to Add HTML Attribute Type with Autocomplete to Vue Props?
Here I'm trying to create a 'type' props with values of HTML input type but it's of type string. Is there a way to do that except of creating enum by myself?
(property) HTMLInputElement.type: string
Returns the content type of the object.
import Input from "./input/Input.vue";

interface SearchInputProps {
  search: string;
  placeholder?: string;
  type?: HTMLInputElement["type"]; // still of type string
}

withDefaults(defineProps<SearchInputProps>(), {
  placeholder: "Search",
  type: "text",
});

const emit = defineEmits<{
  (event: "search-input", input: string): void;
}>();
</script>


When you retrieve the type property of an HTMLInputElement you do in fact receive a string.  This is not unexpected behavior.

It's cool that you're saying that, but the question is still open:
"Is there a way to do that except of creating enum by myself?"

@JustV If HTMLInputElement doesn't contain the exact types you need (it looks like it doesn't), you need to write them yourself. For a search field I'm not sure why you would consider anything but text | search

Just were look for a way to get autocomplete for any of HTML attributes, thanks anyway.
